# Os Module Walk Not Sorting

Tags: python

I am making a game in pygame and python. And I was attempting to animate the player. While testing I used the Walk function from the OS module. When I print the information, it does what it's supposed to. It prints the contents of a given folder, but the contents are out of order. I tried animating anyway, but it just looks wrong. I think I can use the sorted function in some form, but I don't know how. I am also on a mac, if that effects this in anyway. Thanks in advance, here is my code( in a certain file )

```
from os import walk

def import_folder(path):
   for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
       print(img_files)

import_folder('../Graphics/character/run')
```

Again, I was just testing to see if I can access the files this way. Thanks.

Comment: `print(sorted(img_files))`?

Comment: wow, that actually made me feel dumb. Thank you so much